# How to update state after an async call inside a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get a data that is returning from axios get method to a method call on aon object. Instead of returning the value, it's returning the promise. What am I missing here?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    totalResults: ""
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      totalResults: this.fetchData()
        .then(function(res) {
          const r = res.data.totalResults;
          return r;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("error: ", err))
    });
  }
  fetchData = () => {
    return axios.get(
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=8d98dac05ec947d1b891832495641b49"
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.totalResults)}>
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here's the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3kp323n5)

**Note:** This is just a reference code. I can't do setState because I'm trying to call the method from **array.map()** iterator instead.

**Edit:**

This is what actually I'm trying to do: [codesandbox.io/s/n5m3qyn65l](https://codesandbox.io/s/n5m3qyn65l)

For some reason it's showing `Network Error`

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: That's what axios calls return; I'm not sure where the confusion is. You need to setState in the promise resolution handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @DaveNewton I can't do setState on my actual code. This is just a reference code. Actually I had an array of objects that has image guid. I tried to map into the array and using the each guid I wanted to fetch their respective image link.

Comment: If you can't `setState` in your actual code... then I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you don't set *some* state it's all rather pointless, whether it's with the immediately-returned data, or another fetch of data based on the first data fetch. The problem is the same, and you'll run in to it again. If you need to fetch additional data you'll want to wait for all promises to resolve from the secondary fetches, and it's handled in essentially the same way. I'd read up on promises first, then consider switching to a different management mechanism like rxjs etc.

Comment: This is what actually I'm trying to do: codesandbox.io/s/n5m3qyn65l

For some reason it's showing Network Error

Answer (score 0):

You should `setState` after getting the response from `fetchData()` because `fetchData()` will return promise, which you're setting in the state.

Remember, `setState` will do assignment only, you can't expect it wait for asynchronous operation. In that case, try `async/await`

**Updated answer:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/1r22oo804q

Find the inline comments

Comment: I can't do setState on my actual code. This is just a reference code. Actually I had an array of objects that has image guid. I tried to map into the array and using the each guid I wanted to fetch their respective image link.

Comment: You get the concept and understand it from the updated code. If you still not able to solve, you can contact me personally or share the actual code here

Comment: This is what actually I'm trying to do: codesandbox.io/s/n5m3qyn65l For some reason it's showing `Network Error`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Promise.all()` to fetch all images before updating your articles. Like so:

```
const res = response.data;

Promise.all(res.map(article => (
  this.fetchImages(article.featured_media)
    .then(image => ({
      title: article.title.rendered,
      content: article.content.rendered,
      featuredImage: image.guid.rendered
    }))
    .catch(err => console.log("Error fetching image: ", err))
    ))
)
  .then(articles => this.setState({ articles }))
  .catch(err => console.log("Error setting up articles: ", err))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Our basic components state setup

    class myComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                currentSession: {
                    fullNames: [],
                    contactInfo: []
                }
            }}


// Here we make our function to fetch our API data

    fetchData()
        .then(res => {
                let namesData = res.data.name;
                let contactData = res.data.email;

                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    currentSession: {
                         ...prevState.currentSession,
                                        fullNames: Object.assign(namesData),
                                        contactInfo: Object.assign(contactData)
                                    }
                                }));
                              }); 

// Since it's an async call, we'll put in in a 'componentDidMount' method

        componentDidMount() {
            this.fetchData();               
        }
```